# Make a image with appendChild spawn under a html button for html project

Tags: javascript

Basically, what this code does is generates a monkey on click. However, I have a problem with this because when I click, the button moves down because when the monkey generates, it moves to the right of the button. The picture of the monkey is bigger than the button, therefore pushing the button down. I'm not sure how to make the monkey spawn at a certain margin from the top or make up spawn under the button.

```
<input type="button" value="MONKE BUTTON" id="countButton" />
Monke button was pressed - <span id="displayCount">0</span> - times. 
</div>

<script>
var count = 0;
var countButton = document.getElementById("countButton");
var displayCount = document.getElementById("displayCount");
countButton.onclick = function(){
  count++;
  displayCount.innerHTML = count;

}

const button = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    

   const othermonke = document.createElement("img");
   othermonke.src = "./monke.jpg";
   othermonke.width = "200";
   othermonke.height = "200";
   othermonke.alt = "alttext";

   button.parentElement.appendChild(othermonke);
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending the `<img>` elements to `button.parentElement` which corresponds to the parent `<div>` container, just create another container to append the generated images so they always appear below the button. When you use `appendChild` on the buttons parent element, it's appending your `<img>`'s to the end of the parent container. Which makes the `<input>` element and text adjacent with all of the images in the HTML,

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" value="MONKE BUTTON" id="countButton" />
  Monke button was pressed - <span id="displayCount">0</span> - times.
  <img src="./monke.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="alttext">
  <img src="./monke.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="alttext">
  ..
</div>
```

Therefore when a new image is generated its being placed to the right of the button and text on the same line. If the viewport width is small, the images will be forced onto the next line underneath the button, when the viewport width is large the images will appear to the right of the button/text filling the page until the content reaches the end and flows onto the next line. To make things easier, just create a new element `<div class="images">` in the parent container to append the generated images into.

This way you can create a new [block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) element which always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

```js
var count = 0;
var countButton = document.getElementById("countButton");
var displayCount = document.getElementById("displayCount");
countButton.onclick = function(){
  count++;
  displayCount.innerHTML = count;

}

const button = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    
   const images = document.querySelector(".images");
   const othermonke = document.createElement("img");
   othermonke.src = "https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/microsoft/74/monkey_1f412.png";
   othermonke.width = "200";
   othermonke.height = "200";
   othermonke.alt = "alttext";

   images.appendChild(othermonke);
});
```

```css
.images {
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.images img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: .5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="button" value="MONKE BUTTON" id="countButton" />
  Monke button was pressed - <span id="displayCount">0</span> - times.
  <div class="images"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem related to alignment, then you can apply `vertical-align:top` to your button and text like below. So that it will top aligned always.

```js
var count = 0;
var countButton = document.getElementById("countButton");
var displayCount = document.getElementById("displayCount");
countButton.onclick = function(){
  count++;
  displayCount.innerHTML = count;

}

const button = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    

   const othermonke = document.createElement("img");
   othermonke.src = "https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/microsoft/74/monkey_1f412.png";
   othermonke.width = "50";
   othermonke.height = "50";
   othermonke.alt = "alttext";

   button.parentElement.appendChild(othermonke);
});
```

```css
#countButton, #contenSpan {
vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="button" value="MONKE BUTTON" id="countButton" />
<span id="contenSpan">Monke button was pressed - <span id="displayCount">0</span> - times. </span>
</div>
```